# ImageJ - assigning different opaqueness to different colours

Tags: colors, rgb, imagej

I try to create a 3D video using ImageJ and one of its plugins 3DViewer.
My image came from a 8-bit ANALYZE file.  After opening it in ImageJ, I used the LUT to assign a colour to each of 4 entries.  Is there a way to change the opaqueness of each colour?  For example, red needs to be transparent, where as blue and green should be solid.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but it worked.  I saved the original NIfTI file as two separate files (one contains the entires that will be opaque and another with the entires that will be transparent).  I opened both of them on ImageJ,  launched 3DViewer with the first image, then added the one that needs to be transparent.  There's an option in 3DViewer for making the image transparent.